# Is eigenvectors/eigenvalues of symetric matrix related with eigenvectors/eigenvalues of its block?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

$A$ is square symmetric matrix as:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} A_1&A_2 \\ A_3 & A_4 \end{pmatrix}$$
I have two points which need help to understand clearly:
    All blocks $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$ of symmetric $A$ are symmetric too. Is it right?
    Is any relation between eigenvectors/eigenvalues of matrix $A$ and its blocks?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand, what $A$ is ?

Comment: I've edited your post using TeX syntax for better readability. Please, check whether I did unintentionally not change the meaning (and edit the post again, if needed). 
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g.
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559),
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto)
and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Ohh, I'm seeking a editing, and see your correction. Thanks to Martin Sleziak!

Answer (score 3):

$A_1$ and $A_4$ must be symmetric, but $A_2$ and $A_3$ need not (in fact they're not even necessarily square); the condition here is $A_2 = ^tA_3$. Consider:

$$A = \left( \begin{array}{c|cc}
4 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right)$$

I'm not aware of any relation between the eigenvalues of $A$ and the ones of its blocks, for example here $A_1$ has eigenvalue 4, but $A$ itself doesn't have this eigenvalues. As for the eigenvectors, they don't even belong in the same spaces (they're 3-dimensional for $A$ but not for the blocks).

Comment: If there is one more condition: A has size nxn, n is even number, the first thing is right - all blocks are symmetric; A_2 and A_3 are equal?